# Sklearn multi-class logistic regression (one-vs-rest): How to match each coefficient with the iterations in ovr?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have three classes (supermarkets, convenient stores, and grocery stores) and I want to use the logistic regression for classification. I understand how does the one-vs-rest method work and why I get three coefficients by applying `LogReg.coef_`. But what makes me confused is, how can I match each coefficient with the iterations in one-vs-rest?

For example, one of the coefficients must match with the situation that the estimator considers supermarkets as one type and the others as another type. How can I recognize this coefficient?